# Unsubscribing when using the shareReplay operator

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable that performs some relatively taxing work so I need to use the `shareReplay(1)` operator, it's important that I have access to an emitted value immediately as well so `share` won't quite achieve everything I need.

The issue is that when I'm trying to cleanup and unsubscribe the source observable will keep emitting, which I believe is caused by `shareReplay` keeping it alive due to `refCount` defaulting to false. This is also the behavior I need as at application start up the reference count will jump from 1 to 0 to 1 essentially, I don't want to observable restarting on a new subscription.

Is there any way to unsubscribe and stop the source observable emitting when using `shareReplay`? Seems a bit strange to have no way to clean up resources when using that particular operator.

A simple example:

```
const first = interval(10_000).pipe(
   startWith(0),
   withLatestFrom(someOtherObs),
   map(([i, val]) => {
      // some work
   }),
   shareReplay(1)
)

const second = interval(5_000).pipe(
   withLatestFrom(first),
   take(5)
)

const main = interval(5_000).pipe(
   withLatestFrom(first),
   map(([i, val]) => {
      // perform work
   })
)

const app = from([second, main]).pipe(concatAll()).subscribe()
```

Basically `second` will complete before `main` will start (hence the need for `shareReplay`), however it will continue emitting in perpetuity due to the `interval`... Is there anything I can do to avoid this while achieving the same behavior... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you'll need to force the source Observable of `shareReplay(1)` to complete for example with `takeUntil()` operator.

```
const done$ = new Subject();

const first = interval(10_000).pipe(
   startWith(0),
   withLatestFrom(someOtherObs),
   map(([i, val]) => {
      // some work
   }),
   takeUntil(done$),
   shareReplay(1)
)

// ...

done$.next();
```